# Gather uncaught/untested warnings that were fired during testthat::test_dir in R

Tags: r, warnings, testthat

I want to run all the tests and obtain the test results and produced warnings to programmatically create a markdown report showing test outcomes and potential warnings that occurred in the tested code.

But it seems there is no way to obtain or capture warnings during the test run! I understand that tests are executed in a closed environment, but is there really no way to let testthat provide me the thrown warnings?

In the following setup, the `warn_list` variable is always empty.

Three files for the minimal example:

`./tests/testthat.R`

```R
library(testthat)
 
warn_list <- list()
outcome <- withCallingHandlers(

    testthat::test_dir(testthat::test_path()),
   
    warning = function(w) {
        warn_list <<- c(warn_list, list(msg = w$message))
    }
)

rmarkdown::render(input = './tests/create_test_report.Rmd')
```

Note that the `outcome` (and `warn_list`) variable is used in the Rmd file.

`./tests/testthat/test_thrown_warn.R`

```R
test_that("Throws Warning", {

    testthat::expect_equal(
        {
            warning('Example warning fired inside test!')  # WHERE WARN IS THROWN
            5
        }, 5)
   
})
```

`./tests/create_test_report.Rmd`

````
---
title: "test_results_overview"
output: md_document
---

## Produced warnings during the tests:
 
```{r warnings_during_testing, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(warn_list)                     # WHERE I TRY TO SHOW IT
```
````

Comment: I suspect `testthat` is catching the warnings.  Maybe setting the `reporter` argument to something non-default (or customized) will get you what you want.

Comment: Good remark, I read about the different (quite undocumented) reporters, but didn't experiment with them. If I remember correctly, the testthat_results class object the tests return remains the same though...? Will take a look

Comment: If you doubt between the answers:
Choose 'user2554330' his answer if you only want the warning (or skips or failures) itself.
Choose my answer if you like the line where it occurred and some more context like file/test/context etc.

Comment: Actually, the `awarning` object mention in my answer is more than just a condition object.  `awarning$test` will give the name of the test, and the location can be found from the `awarning$srcref` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `SummaryReporter` reporter object records warnings.  As you mention in your comment, these are very minimally documented, but this seems to do it:

```
library(testthat)
summary <- SummaryReporter$new()
test_file("somewarnings.R", reporter = summary)
summary$warnings$as_list()
```

Each of the warnings results in an entry in the list from the last statement.  They are stored as condition objects, so you can do stuff like

```
awarning <- summary$warnings$as_list()[[1]]
getSrcFilename(awarning$srcref)
```

Comment: This is awesome! I figured out some alternative way which I will also post, but yours is way better I think, so will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is actually available within the `testthat_results` object.
It does include specific test case responses like warnings, skipped tests or errors of crashed tests, but the content is not nicely structured.

E.g. in the testcase shown in the example, it will show three result fields, while there are only two 'expect_...' statements. The middle one will be of class `c('expectation_warning', 'expectation', 'condition')` and contain the warning object.

The alternative solution is to obtain those warnings (and optionally error and skips as a bonus) from the outcomes like this:

```R
outcome <- testthat::test_dir(testthat::test_path(), stop_on_failure = FALSE)

create_warn_df <- function(res) {
    data.frame(test = res$test, warning_msg = res$message)
}
 
warn_df <- data.frame()
for (i_test in seq_along(outcome)) {
    tst <- outcome[[i_test]]
   
    for (i_res in seq_along(tst$results)) {
        res <- tst$results[[i_res]]
       
        if (is(res, "expectation_warning")) {
            warn_df <- rbind(warn_df, create_warn_df(res))
        } 
    }
}
 
knitr::kable(warn_df)
```

Note: that 'create_warning_str' will format the table and could obtain much more information, like stack etc. from the warning object.

The test results are located in `outcome[[X]]$results[[Y]]` where `X` is the file that is being processed and `Y` is the test case (or warning, as described earlier). The number of `Y` elements are not equal to the number of test cases.

### A more advanced example:

This one includes the line number of where it occurred and includes errors and skips in addition. It also shows the 'file' instead of the 'test' (name).

```R
create_warn_df <- function(file, src_ref, warn_msg) {
    data.frame('file' = file, 'line' = getSrcLocation(src_ref), 'warning_msg' = warn_msg)
}
 
warn_df <- data.frame()
for (i_test in seq_along(outcome)) {
    tst <- outcome[[i_test]]
   
    for (i_res in seq_along(tst$results)) {
        res <- tst$results[[i_res]]
       
        if (is(res, "expectation_warning")) {
            warn_df <- rbind(warn_df, create_warn_df(tst$file, res$srcref, res$message))
        } else if (is(res, "expectation_error")) {
            warn_df <- rbind(warn_df, create_warn_df(tst$file, res$srcref, paste('An error crashed this test:', res$message)))
        } else if (is(res, "expectation_skip")) {
            warn_df <- rbind(warn_df, create_warn_df(tst$file, res$srcref, paste('A test is skipped,', res$message)))
        }
    }
}
 
knitr::kable(warn_df)
```